# Others can't hear me on google meet, even if I'm unmuted. And I'm audible on other apps

Tags: google-meet

I've checked the granted permission for the microphone and it is showing "Allow".
Unlike Google Meet, others can hear me on other apps like Zoom (using the same headphones).
Note : Even when using the in built microphone it is not working.

I have important meetings scheduled.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please show what you tried to set the microphone to be used in Google Meet and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Official help article: [Change your computer’s video and audio settings](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9302964?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén I looked for the permissions the google meet web app has. And it had the permission to use the microphone. Second, I tried using different headphones. But none of them helped.

Comment: Have you read the article that I liked in my previous comment? It's about Google Meet settings, not about permissions (P.S. the article should include the required permissions)

Comment: @Rubén Yes, I did. I figured out the solution. Read the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, it's kind of a weird solution I figured out, but yet an interesting one.

As I mentioned, the microphone was working properly on the other app I use i.e. Zoom, and members in the meeting had no problem hearing me.

And the solution to the problem was linked to a setting in the Zoom app i.e. when in a meeting you can adjust the input level of your microphone. Strangely the setting for the microphone input level (in zoom) applied to the Google Meet microphone input level too.

So, the last input level of your microphone in Zoom also applied to the Google Meet, no matter if you've left the Zoom meeting.

After readjusting the microphone input level, in the Zoom app (by scheduling an instant meeting), I could make myself audible to other members on Google Meet, itself. Weird, but that worked. I crossed checked too.